# Retrieving entire data collection from a RavenDB

Tags: ravendb

I have a requirement where I need to fetch the entire data collection `Users` from RavenDB and compare the retrieved result set with another set of data. There are close to 4000 records in this particular collection.

Because Raven is Safe By Default, I keep getting an exception for either `Number of requests per session exceeded` or it returns the maximum 128 records.

I don't want to set the property `Session.Advanced.MaxNumberOfRequestsPerSession` to a higher value.

What query should I use to get the count of all the records? What is the ideal approach to handle this situation?

Comment: In case anyone only goes as far as the first answer the one by Jon Adams is a good way. Here is a link to an article introducing the "new" feature. https://ayende.com/blog/161249/ravendbs-querying-streaming-unbounded-results

Answer (score 21, accepted):

You use paging, and read this 1024 items at a time.

```
int start = 0;
while(true)
{
   var current = session.Query<User>().Take(1024).Skip(start).ToList();
   if(current.Count == 0)
          break;

   start+= current.Count;
   allUsers.AddRange(current);

}
```

Comment: I see that above solution works because the total no. of records is close to 4000, so no of queries would be < 30. Just curious, what would be the way to handle a similar scenario wherein Total no of records are > 30*1024, i.e. if they are more than say 31k count?

Comment: @annantDev You could track the number of requests made within the session. Once it reaches 30, dispose old session, create new session and continue reading.

Answer (score 14):

This question was posted before this feature was available in RavenDB, but in case anyone else stumbles upon this now...

The encouraged way to do this is via the [Streaming API](http://ravendb.net/docs/2.5/client-api/advanced/unbounded-results?version=2.5). The RavenDB client batches the stream so it can automatically 'page' the requests/responses to/from the server. If you opt in to using the Streaming API, the client assumes you "know what you're doing" and does not check the 128/1024/30 limits that are used for regular queries.

```
var query = session.Query<User>();
 
using (var enumerator = session.Advanced.Stream(query)) {
    while (enumerator.MoveNext()) {
        allUsers.Add(enumerator.Current.Document);
    }
}

var count = allUsers.Count;
```

Tip: Though this is the encouraged way to solve the problem... As a general rule it is best to avoid the situation to start with. What if there are a million records? That `allUsers` list is going to get huge. Maybe an index or transform could be done first to filter out what data you actually need to display to the user/process? Is this for reporting purposes? Maybe RavenDB should be automatically exporting to a SQL server with reporting services on it? Etc...

Comment: The Streaming API is not available when using Shards in v2.5 and older. (Not sure about v3.0+)

Comment: StreamQuery does not support querying dynamic indexes. So to use this method, you would need to make an index first to query upon.

Answer (score 2):

I like Al Dass solution of getting ids to operate on instead of complete large objects. Also getting the ids directly from the index. However the recursion scares me a bit (even though I think it might be ok) and I removed the reflection.

```
public List<string> GetAllIds<T>()
{
var allIds = new List<string>();
IDocumentSession session = null;

try
{
    session = documentStore.OpenSession();
    int queryCount = 0;
    int start = 0;
    while (true)
    {
        var current = session.Advanced.DocumentQuery<T>()
            .Take(1024)
            .Skip(start)
            .SelectFields<string>("__document_id")
            .AddOrder("__document_id")
            .ToList();

        if (current.Count == 0)
            break;
        allIds.AddRange(current);

        queryCount += 1;
        start += current.Count;

        if (queryCount == 30)
        {
            queryCount = 0;
            session.Dispose();
            session = documentStore.OpenSession();
        }
    }
}
finally
{
    if (session != null)
    {
        session.Dispose();
    }
}

return allIds;
}
```

also, this is updated to ravendb 3

Answer (score 1):

Building up on the Ayende answer, here is a complete method, that does overcome the problem of 30 queries per session and indeed return all documents of the supplied class:

```
    public static List<T> getAll<T>(DocumentStore docDB) {
        return getAllFrom(0, new List<T>(), docDB);
    }

    public static List<T> getAllFrom<T>(int startFrom, List<T> list, DocumentStore docDB ) {
        var allUsers = list;

        using (var session = docDB.OpenSession())
        {
            int queryCount = 0;
            int start = startFrom;
            while (true)
            {
                var current = session.Query<T>().Take(1024).Skip(start).ToList();
                queryCount += 1;
                if (current.Count == 0)
                    break;

                start += current.Count;
                allUsers.AddRange(current);

                if (queryCount >= 30)
                {
                    return getAllFrom(start, allUsers, docDB);
                }
            }
        }
        return allUsers;
    }
```

I hope it is not too hacky to do it like this.

Comment: The answer by Renato Kovarish has several advantages over this one. This answer uses recurssion.

Comment: @BrokeMyLegBiking True, the recursion here is unnecessary. But thies one does at least handle the 30 request per session limit that the other referenced answer does not.

Answer (score 1):

I honestly prefer the following function:

```
    public IEnumerable<T> GetAll<T>()
    {
        List<T> list = new List<T>();

        RavenQueryStatistics statistics = new RavenQueryStatistics();

        list.AddRange(_session.Query<T>().Statistics(out statistics));
        if (statistics.TotalResults > 128)
        {
            int toTake = statistics.TotalResults - 128;
            int taken = 128;
            while (toTake > 0)
            {
                list.AddRange(_session.Query<T>().Skip(taken).Take(toTake > 1024 ? 1024 : toTake));
                toTake -= 1024;
                taken += 1024;
            }
        }

        return list;
    }
```

[]'s

Comment: You will hit the 30 request per session limit pretty quick with this code, as written anyway, without expanding the request limit.

Answer (score 1):

With a slight twist on [@capaj's post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14040576/271992). Here is a generic way of getting all the document IDs as a list of strings. Note the use of `Advanced.LuceneQuery<T>(idPropertyName)`, `SelectFields<T>(idPropertyName)` and `GetProperty(idPropertyName)` to make things generic. The default assumes `"Id"` is a valid property on the given `<T>` (which should be the case 99.999% of the time). In the event you have some other property as your `Id` you can pass it in as well.

```cs
public static List<string> getAllIds<T>(DocumentStore docDB, string idPropertyName = "Id") {
   return getAllIdsFrom<T>(0, new List<string>(), docDB, idPropertyName);
}

public static List<string> getAllIdsFrom<T>(int startFrom, List<string> list, DocumentStore docDB, string idPropertyName ) {
    var allUsers = list;

    using (var session = docDB.OpenSession())
    {
        int queryCount = 0;
        int start = startFrom;
        while (true)
        {
            var current = session.Advanced.LuceneQuery<T>().Take(1024).Skip(start).SelectFields<T>(idPropertyName).ToList();
            queryCount += 1;
            if (current.Count == 0)
                break;

            start += current.Count;
            allUsers.AddRange(current.Select(t => (t.GetType().GetProperty(idPropertyName).GetValue(t, null)).ToString()));

            if (queryCount >= 28)
            {
                return getAllIdsFrom<T>(start, allUsers, docDB, idPropertyName);
            }
        }
    }
    return allUsers;
}
```

An example of where/how I use this is when making a `PatchRequest` in RavenDb using the `BulkInsert` session. In some cases I may have hundreds of thousands of documents and can't afford to load all the documents in memory just to re-iterate over them again for the patch operation... thus the loading of only their string IDs to pass into the `Patch` command.

```
void PatchRavenDocs()
{
    var store = new DocumentStore
    {
        Url = "http://localhost:8080",
        DefaultDatabase = "SoMeDaTaBaSeNaMe"
    };

    store.Initialize();

    // >>>here is where I get all the doc IDs for a given type<<<
    var allIds = getAllIds<SoMeDoCuMeNtTyPe>(store);    

    // create a new patch to ADD a new int property to my documents
    var patches = new[]{ new PatchRequest { Type = PatchCommandType.Set, Name = "SoMeNeWPrOpeRtY" ,Value = 0 }};

    using (var s = store.BulkInsert()){
        int cntr = 0;
        Console.WriteLine("ID Count " + allIds.Count);
        foreach(string id in allIds)
        {
            // apply the patch to my document
            s.DatabaseCommands.Patch(id, patches);

            // spit out a record every 2048 rows as a basic sanity check
            if ((cntr++ % 2048) == 0)
                Console.WriteLine(cntr + " " + id);
        }
    }
}
```

Hope it helps. :)